# Asp.net Web Api Token Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How to implement Token Based Authentication without using Katana ? there is any way to implement without Katana ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Owin(Katana), you should write your custom authentication.

There is a good example [here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005485/RESTful-Day-sharp-Security-in-Web-APIs-Basic)